# Is there a totally disconnected topological space which is not Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

**Definition:** A topological space $X$ is totally disconnected if for all $x \in X$ , the connected  component of $X$ containing $x$ is $\{x  \}$.

My question is:

> Is there a totally disconnected topological space so which is not Hausdorff?

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240439/totally-disconnected-space-that-is-not-t-2?rq=1).